# How can you rotate a 3D object (perspective view) in PowerPoint

Tags: animation, rotation, jquery-animate, powerpoint, perspective

After a some unsuccessful googling, I could not find a way to animate a single perspective view/skewed object without using any VBA, Flash, Java, etc.  If you try to apply a rotation of any sorts to a 3D object that was skewed or put into a sort of perpective view in PowerPoint 2010, it would simply rotate the object about it's x or y axis as if it took the picture and rotated it on a flat surface.  I wanted to take a smart art object, skew it a bit, and rotate it along it z axis but yet retain the perspective view of it keeping the rotation skewed. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

So, I generated a sort of 3 frames per second animation which uses multiple copies of the same object (3 instances in my case), rotated each subsequent instance about 30 degrees off previous rotation.  I then skewed each object to where it would overlay over one another (which required a little x, y adjustments).  I then applied an animation to each object that would simulate a rotation.

The first instance (object parent) I applied an animation that made the object disappear after a mouse click with a duration of 00.01 and 00.00 delay.

The second instance (copy of parent that has been rotated 30 degrees clockwise) I applied an animation that made it appear after previous 00.01 duration and 00.00 delay.
I applied a 2nd animation (via the Add Animation toolbar button) that would make it dissappear after previous, duration setting of 00.25 and 00.00 delay.

The third instance (copy of the parent that has been rotated about 60 degrees clockwise) I applied an animation exactly set to start after previous that mirrors the same settings and of the second instance. Remember, you would need to also create another animation for the third instance that makes it dissapear as well (using the same settings that mirrors the 2nd instance 2nd animation mentioned above)

What this basically does, it creates a sort of moving animation when played back.

To have a longer animation, I created a forth instance which is just a copy of the 1st instance (parent object) that has the same appear/dissappear animations tied to it, and starts after previous (third instance in this case) animation.

I copied the 2nd, 3rd, 4th objects and pasted them into the slide again, creating a 5th, 6th, and 7th object instances (animation settings are retain). All I had to do is select the new animation instances of those new pasted objects, and edit the time on them to start after previous.  Repeat this pattern until your desired length of animated time is desired.

In order to keep the very last object visable after all the animation stops, you will need to remove the last animation instance from whatever the last object in sequence is (the animation that causes the object to dissappear).

When you initate the playback, you will have a sort of rotating perspective viewed object.  Note, on slower computers, you may notice some brief flashes as the animation is played back due to the smallest duration you can make an object that dissappears is 00.01 before the next animation kicks in.

Helpful Tip:
If your objects do not seem to align just right, what I did is to overlay all the copies and adjust the skew for each one individually until they aligned up correctly.  Note, I did have to adjust the x and y axises a little bit (how much to have to adjust depends on how much you have it skewed).  For example, my 1st object was rotated y=105.5, 2nd object was x=31 y=108.5, third object was x=52 y=117, and fourth (repeat of the 1st object) object y=105.5, etc.